# Unwanted TUPE Transfer

Tags: england-and-wales, employment

Suppose that Law Firm A has a team of solicitors dedicated to Client X. Client X decides to procure from Law Firm B instead, and there is a service provision change under TUPE. The team of solicitors would therefore transfer to Law Firm B.

It appears that even if Law Firm A and a solicitor in the transferring team both wish to prevent the transfer, and keep the solicitor employed by Law Firm A for other clients, that there is no straightforward way to do so. There are two potential options, but both seem to have different disadvantages:

- The solicitor could object to the transfer, and not be transferred. Law Firm A could then rehire the solicitor. However, this would be treated as new employment, and if the solicitors were part of a collective bargaining agreement, the employee may lose seniority as a result.
- Law Firm A could assign the solicitor to a different team before the transfer since TUPE only applies to employees assigned immediately before the transfer. However, this is likely to be at least slightly disruptive to the transfer of activity between Law Firm A and Law Firm B.

If neither of the above happens, then it appears TUPE requires the transfer. Is that correct? If both Law Firm A and the employee agree to ignore TUPE and the employee keeps working for Law Firm A, does Law Firm B have any cause of action? It may admittedly not be practical for them to sue, given the employee could in any case object or at the very least give notice once they had transferred.

Comment: it doesn't seem that TUPE *requires* employees to change companies; it protects employees when they do.

Comment: TUPE transfers are automatic though, with the right for the employee to object. If they object, section 4(8) of the TUPE serves to end the employment contract altogether, seemingly even if neither the outgoing employer nor the employee wish it to. As I mention, the employer can rehire the employee, but there is the potential collective bargaining issue, and there may well be other considerations there as well with it being a new employment.